# ExifInterface always returning rotation 0

Tags: android, xamarin.android

**I get a rotate picture from a custom camera, I saves the image to get path to use it on ExifInterface, and to make it the right direction I've used on ExifInterface, but it always returns with a value of 0, what could be the problem? (I run an emulator)**

**Thank you**

**Here is my OnPictureTaken Method:**

```
public async void OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
    {
        var targetWidth = 1080;
        var cameraParams = camera.GetParameters();
        var ratio = ((decimal)cameraParams.PictureSize.Height) / cameraParams.PictureSize.Width;

        var w = cameraParams.PictureSize.Width >= targetWidth
            ? targetWidth
            : cameraParams.PictureSize.Width;

        var h = cameraParams.PictureSize.Width >= targetWidth
            ? (int)Math.Floor(targetWidth * ratio)
            : cameraParams.PictureSize.Height;

        Java.IO.File sdDir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
        Java.IO.File pictureFileDir = new Java.IO.File(sdDir, "RDCCameraImages");

        if (!pictureFileDir.Exists() && !pictureFileDir.Mkdirs())
        {
            return;
        }
        String photoFile = "Picture_"   + "aaa.jpg";
        String imageFilePath = pictureFileDir.Path + Java.IO.File.Separator + photoFile;
        Java.IO.File pictureFile = new Java.IO.File(imageFilePath);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.Write(data);
        fos.Close();

        ExifInterface exif;

        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.AbsolutePath);
        int orientation = ei.GetAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TagOrientation, (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Normal);//return 0

        var imageStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        using (var bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length))
        using (var scaled = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bm, w, h, false))
        {
            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
            switch (orientation)
            {

                case (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate90:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(scaled, 90);
                    break;

                case (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate180:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(scaled, 180);
                    break;

                case (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate270:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(scaled, 270);
                    break;

                case (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Normal:
                    rotatedBitmap = scaled;
                    break;
                default:
                    rotatedBitmap = scaled;
                    break;
            }
            await scaled.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 90, imageStream);
            await imageStream.FlushAsync();
        }
   }  
   public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.PostRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.CreateBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.Width, source.Height,
                                   matrix, true);
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem if rotaion is always 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ExifInterface, and to make it the right direction I've used on ExifInterface, but it always returns with a value of 0, what could be the problem?

[ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) doesn't work like that. In your codes you just created a new picture and save it in your device and if I understand it correctly, you expect `ExifInterface` to detect the Orientation automatically. Well it is not that much smart, `ExifInterface` can only get the information that we have previously saved into that image using `ExifInterface.SetAttribute`:

```
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.AbsolutePath);
//set the attribute
ei.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagOrientation, "90");
//save the attributes
ei.SaveAttributes();

//For Test I created a totally new ExifInterface
ExifInterface ei2 = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.AbsolutePath);
//we get the Information of previously saved orientation
var orientationInfo = ei2.GetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagOrientation);
//orientationInfo=90
```

**How to get Camera Orientation?**

You can use CameraInfo to get orientation of current camera:

```
int cameraId=0;
CameraInfo cameraInfo=null;
for (int i = 0; i < Camera.NumberOfCameras; i++)
{
    CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
    Camera.GetCameraInfo(i, info);
    if (info.Facing == CameraInfo.CameraFacingBack)
    {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraInfo = info;
    }
}
//Open Camera
mCamera = Camera.Open(cameraId);
if (cameraInfo != null)
{
     var orientation = cameraInfo.Orientation;
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but I need to get image orientation when his taken. you know how?  ei.GetAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TagOrientation, (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Normal) return always 0

Comment: The image orientation and camera's orientation are identical, you just need to store the camera 's orientation locally and rotate the image from this orientation.